# getting a http-304-status, but still data is transfered

Tags: http, browser, http-status-code-304

I am wondering about this observation:

I load a website for the second time and the network-module in firefox developer-tools tells me, e.g. for the html document: status=304, type=html, size=60kb.

Some other assets of type=js or css are also flagged as status=304, but have size>0

I am wondering why firefox seems to download an asset that is not modified.

With images it seems to work as expected: whenever an asset is of type=jpeg or png, and status=304, than size=0

Is there any explanation for that?

Comment: is your question correctly answered? If yes, maybe you can kindly "accept" my answer?

Comment: oh yes...  sorry... done...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1250466) in Firefox developer-tools. The "Transferred" and "Size" column in "Network" panel works incorrect for `304 Not Modified` response.

The "Size" column should display the size of resource (after de-compression if the response is compressed), no matter it is retrieved directly from cache, or retrieved from cache after `304` response, or retrieved from server. In your case, the html/css/js requests work fine, but the jpeg/png requests work incorrectly, the size should not be 0.

The "Transferred" column should display the bytes transferred through network. Normally it is smaller than "Size" as the response will be compressed. For `304` response, the "transferred" value would be a pretty small number, but would never be 0 (request URL, request headers, response headers etc.).

Even for Firefox, it does not work consistently. In "FirefoxDeveloperEdition", for `304` response, jpeg/png requests work exactly the same as other html/css/js requests. However, in commonly used "Firefox", the "Size" is 0 and the "Transferred" is "-".